# Must isset() be used before checking if a variable exist?

Tags: php

To my understanding, in oppose to javascript which offers the convenient `if (var) {}`, even if `var` doesn't exist, in PHP you have to use `if (isset(var)) {}`, or `if (isset(var) && var) {}`.

Today I've stumbled upon a [login tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/10/cool-login-system-php-jquery/) that seems to be from a reliable source, in which `isset` is not used:

```
if(!$_SESSION['id']):
```

[From the linked page, demo.php section, line 15]

On my local sever, this line breaks when `$_SESSION['id']` is not set, which is, IMHO, an expected behaviour. `$_SESSION['id']` is not defined prior to this line.

**Is there a mysterious way to avoid the annoying `isset()` check?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your application doesn't "break", because it is just a notice and yes: You should *always* test the existence of array keys, if you are unsure, whether they exists, or not.

```
$defaults = array('id' => null);
$session = array_merge($defaults, $_SESSION);
```

Now you can be sure, that $session has a key `id`.

However, your can suppress warnings and notices with `@`

```
if (!@$_SESSION['id']) { /* .. */ }
```

But usually if you ever touch the `@` key:

- You have a *really* good reason
- You did something wrong :)

In a clean application you need `@` only in some very rare cases.

A word at the end: *Never* use values from outside without validation!

Answer (score 2):

`if(!$_SESSION['id'])` will just check if the session variable is blank. `isset` checks if it's `NULL`. Personally [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) is the way to go. It checks:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)